# Schema Validation not validating mutiple entries in Json

Tags: java, json, validation, jsonschema

JsonSchema validation passes, even if the element is repeating itself. The schema tries to prevent the same using **"additionalProperties" as false**, and **"maxProperties" as 1**.

I have the following json file with one of the field repeating.

```
 {
  "stats": "56989",
   "stats": "56989"
}
```

I tried validating this against the below schema:-

```
  {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://jsonschema.net#",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "maxProperties": 1,
  "properties": {
    "stats": {
      "id": "http://jsonschema.net/stats#",
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 5,
      "minLength": 5,
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "maxProperties": 1
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "stats"
  ]
}
```

The json validates successfully against the schema. Though I am giving **maxProperties=1**, the validation passes.

Please let me know how to check repeating elements in Json Schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your test JSON is invalid.  Repeated properties in an object is undefined in JSON.  The second occurrence of `stats` would either be ignored or it would override the first occurrence.  But, it in end, there would only be one occurrence of `stats`.  When your test data is read into memory, it looks like `{ "stats": "56989" }` and therefore validates successfully.

In order to test `additionalProperties` and/or `maxProperties`, your test data needs to include unique keys.  For example `{ "stats", "56989", "foo": "bar" }` would be an appropriate test case.